# PostgreSQL 9.X Create Procedure

Tags: postgresql

I know that all PostgreSQL 9.* versions are outdated and EOL.

I'm asking for educational purposes, so the outdated version doesn't matter to me. Please don't answer 'It's old'.

I know that PostgreSQL versions 10 and earlier did not support the `create Procedure` syntax.

If you want to create a stored procedure in PostgreSQL before Postgres 11, I saw an article telling you to create a CREATE Function statement by writing the Return Type as Void.

However, whether the return type is Void or Integer, there is no way to distinguish whether the object to be searched is a function or a procedure.

An example query that creates a function and a procedure in PostgreSQL is as follows.

### Function

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION addfunc(a INTEGER, b INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$ BEGIN
    RETURN a+b;
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

### Procedure (1) - Return Void

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION stamp_user(id int, comment text) RETURNS void AS $$ 
      #variable_conflict use_variable 
         DECLARE 
           curtime timestamp := now(); 
         BEGIN 
         UPDATE users SET last_modified = curtime, comment = comment 
            WHERE users.id = id; 
         END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

### Procedure(2) - No Return

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION cubed(INOUT x int) AS $$
BEGIN
    x := x^3;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The following query was written to inquire about functions and procedures, and as a result, there was no clue to distinguish between functions and procedures.

```sql
select
        ns.nspname as schemaName
    ,   proc.proname as routine_name
    ,   pg_get_functiondef(proc.oid) as definition
    ,   pg_get_function_arguments(proc.oid) as arguments
    ,   lang.lanname as lang_name
    ,   obj_description(proc.oid) as comment
    ,   proiswindow
    ,   provolatile
    ,   procost
    ,   prorows
    ,   prosecdef
    ,   proleakproof
    ,   proisstrict
    ,   proretset
    ,   type.typname as returntype
from pg_proc as proc
join pg_namespace as ns on proc.pronamespace  = ns.oid
join pg_language as lang on proc.prolang = lang.oid
join pg_type as type on proc.prorettype = type.oid
where nspname ='{schemaName}'
and proc.proisagg = false
```

In PostgreSQL 11 and later versions, if it is created with `create function`, it is a function, and if it is created with `create procedure`, it is a procedure.

This can be checked through the prokind attribute (p:procedure / f:function)

In other words, I think it is a strange reference point to distinguish between a function and a procedure that the return type is Void and not.

How to differentiate between Function and Procedure across all versions of PostgreSQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For convenience, I called it 9.X. Is it not that x represents 10 in Roman numerals? lol

Comment: I don't think you can achieve what you want, by only looking at `pg_proc` with a statement that works across all versions (supported or not). You will need to check the _version_ of the server you are connected to. If it's 11 or later, use `pg_proc.prokind`, otherwise it's always a function

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Currently Postgresql 9,10,11,12,13,14 are all installed.

As you said, in PostgreSQL 11 or later, you can distinguish between p and f as Prokind.

But in PostgreSQL 9, 10 version there is no prokind.
You said If it's 11 or later, use pg_proc.prokind, otherwise it's always a function, that's the crux of my question.

Why is it always a function? What is the rationale for this?

So how do I tell if it's a Procedure or a Function?

Comment: Before 11, it is always a function  because there was no `create procedure` before that. Postgres had only functions back then.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If so, are all posts about how to create Procedures, create queries, etc. in PostgreSQL versions prior to 11 nonsense? If so, are all posts about how to create Procedures, create queries, etc. in PostgreSQL versions prior to 11 nonsense?

I'm not ignoring your comment, but I've seen a lot of posts about creating Procedures. I'm confused which one is correct.

Comment: Before Postgres introduced real procedures, most people used the terms "function" and "procedure" as synonyms because in the end the difference isn't that big (except for transaction handling). Even the `create trigger` statement used `execute procedure` although Postgres had no (real) procedures.